# My plant came out with new species with black stem in the middle of the leaves. Is that normal?

Tags: houseplants

My plant came out with new species with black stem in the middle of the leaves. Is that normal? [image]

Comment: New leaves, probably not a new species unless this is a whole new plant that sprouted in the same pot as another plant. Could be a random mutation if it's the same plant and didn't have black center ribs before. Can't tell whcih it might be from the question and picture. More details, please?